# Is there a general rule for which types of nouns end in -archy vs. -cracy?

Tags: nouns, suffixes, morphology

Why do we use *democracy* vs. *demarchy* and *anarchy* vs. *anocracy*?

Comment: I blame the patriocracy! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to Liddell & Scott, *An Intermediate Greek–English Lexicon* (1889), the root word κρατος (*kratos*) in ancient Greek meant "*strength*, *might*"—and more generally, "*power*" or "*rule*, *sway*, *sovereignty*." The same lexicon reports that αρχη (*arche*) meant "a beginning, origin, first cause," but also "*the first place* or *power*, *sovereignty*, *dominion*, *command*." The Greek roots thus have considerable overlap, but the connotations of αρχη may have included a stronger sense of hereditary or historical primacy than those of κρατος.

Today both *-archy* and *-cracy* are centrally associated with the idea of ruling. Michael Quinion, *Ologies and Isms: Word Beginnings and Endings* (Oxford, 2002) has this to say about the suffixes:

> **-cracy** Also **-crat**, **-cratic**, and **-cratical**. *Government*, *rule*, or *influence* [Greek *kratia*, power or rule.]
>
> Many forms ending in **-cracy** have been coined, though only a small number are at all well known; most can mean either a system of influence or rule or a society o ruled, as with *democracy*, rule through elected representatives; a few can also refer to the rulers as a group, as with *aristocracy* (Greek *aristos*, best), rule by members of the highest social class.
>
> ...
>
> **-archy** Also **-arch**. *Government; rule of a particular type; a chief or ruler*. [Greek *arkhes*, ruler; *arkhein*, to rule.]
>
> Words in **-archy** are abstract nouns for types of government, leadership, or social influence or organization. They correspond to nouns in **-arch** for a person or people who rule or command in that way. For example, a *monarch* (Greek *monos*, alone or single) is a sovereign head of state, in a type of government called *monarchy*.

Among the words Quinion lists in a table headed "**-cracy** Government, rule, or influence," are these:

> *aristocracy*, *autocracy*, *bureaucracy*, *democracy*, *gerontocracy*, *meritocracy*, *mobocracy*, *plutocracy*, *theocracy*

Among the words that Quinion lists in a table headed " **-archy** Government or rule" are these:

> *anarchy*, *autarchy*, *hierarchy*, *matriarchy*, *monarchy*, *oligarchy*, *patriarchy*, *synarchy*

Because many English speakers when presented with the suffix *-archy* may think first of *monarchy* and when presented with the suffix *-cracy* may think first of *democracy*, they may suppose that a stronger distinction exists between the tendencies of the two suffixes than actually exists.

The range of types of rule or government comprehended by English words with each ending is extremely broad, and I don't see any pattern in the choice of one or the other that offers a reliable basis for predicting which ending a new form is more likely to adopt. For example, "rule by children" might on the model of *gerontocracy* be styled *paidocracy*, or on the strength of *matriarchy* and *patriarchy* be named *paidarchy*.

Also, Quinion's definitions find very little difference between *autarchy* ("a system of government by one person with absolute power") and *autocracy* ("rule by one person with absolute power").

Answer (score 1):

The suffixes have different meanings:

*[-archy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-arch)* means rule:  *Monarchy*: rule of one, *anarchy*: no rule, *oligarchy*: rule of few

*[-cracy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-cracy)* means government: *Democracy*: government of the people, *meritocracy*: government by merit

You could say "demarchy", which would mean "rule of the people", or "rule by the people", but you wouldn't be saying what you'd want to say.  A democracy is not ruled by people, but rather elected representatives.  Or, in a pure democracy, there is no ruler at all, but rather everything is voted on by everyone.

Likewise, an anocracy could be a totalitarian dictatorship (it says nothing of rulers; just that there is no government).  For example, Somalia could be called an anocracy because they have no government.  But that doesn't mean that people are free to do what they please; they still face the wrath and control of local warlords and other rulers.

Comment: All government is *of* the people; what makes a democracy is when it is also *by* the people. Your free dictionary links, if we correct the *-arch* to *-archy,* each yield *both* "rule" and "government" as synonyms. Perhaps more to the point then, the roots are the noun κράτος *might, force,* and the verb ἄρχω, *to lead, be first, begin.*

Answer (score 1):

The only case I have seen where both endings are in use is *autocracy* vs *autarchy*.

The roots κράτος *might*, *force*, and ἄρχω, *to lead*, *be first*, *begin*, suggest different emphases:

An emphasis for *-cracy* on where the power lies and how the power is maintained, and on the use of force to establish a system of government (war/revolution);

An emphasis for *-archy* on leadership and position, as in a word like *hierarchy* and cognates like *arch*.

Intuitively, as a native speaker who has learned primarily from usage rather than reading dictionaries and etymologies, I feel that *-archy* represents something more formal and structural in nature, while *-cracy* is more descriptive and less rigid it its application - viz. *-cracy* is about the flow of power but *-archy* about the description of positional relationships.

These intuitions seem to apply generally but be recognizable specifically in how one views the contrast pair with *auto-* (self, by one's self).