# Opposite of '-cracy/-archy'?

Tags: greek, politics, government

*Something* + *-cracy*/[*-archy*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215698/111427) (“strength, power”) produces a word meaning ‘rule by those who are/have/were whatever the *something* is’. For example, ‘plutocracy’ is *pluto-* (“wealth”) + *-cracy* and means ‘rule by the wealthy’, whilst ‘ptochocracy’ is *ptocho-* (“poverty”) + *-cracy* and means ‘rule by the poor’.

However, say one wanted to make some sort of point by describing different types of rule based not on who *has* the power, but who *doesn't*. How would you do so?

Theory 1: Is there a suffix in English, or that can be derived from Greek, that is antonymic to *-cracy* (meaning “weakness, powerlessness”)?

Theory 2: Is the answer to stick an *a-* somewhere, for example in either ‘**a**ptochocracy’ or ‘ptocho**a**cracy’ to mean ‘a situation in which the poor have no power’? I feel like *-acracy* would make more intuitive sense, if this is the case.

*This question was inspired by the discussions on [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463416/androcracy-gynocracy-are-hyponyms-of-and-oligocracy-oligarchy-is-a-hype), but was distinct enough that I wanted to ask it separately.*

Comment: It's not a matter of needing a "negated" alternative to the ***-cracy*** suffix - you just need to come up with an appropriate element *before* the suffix. ***Slaves**,* for example, don't usually have any power, but [according to Oxford Dictionaries](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/07/18/words-ending-with-cracy/) they would be running the show in a ***dulocracy***.

Comment: An alpha privative has to come first to be recognized as such. Are you trying to coin a word with Greek roots meaning the disenfranchisement or politicsl marginalization of a particular group?

Comment: On the one hand, have you looked up suffix antonyms? Soft, as opposed to Hard; Endings, as opposed to Origins, etc? On the other, the question itself seems a bit of a 'liar's paradox' - if the wealthy are ruling and have power, how can the poor rule or have (the same) power? You can talk about hard power and soft power - personal power and institutional power. Not sure where you want to go with this.

Comment: Usually medical, the suffix ***-penia*** denotes a deficiency or lack of the root it's attached to (e.g. leukopenia = deficiency of white cells). You could form an expression that means a lack of power or control, but I don't see how you'd attach it to a certain group.

Comment: @KarlG Exactly. So a society in which the wealthy held all the power would be called a ‘plutocracy’, but could also be called a ‘ptocho**something**’ if one wanted to draw focus to the powerless rather than the empowered, and that **something** is what I'm after.